# A material that gets tough when current is passed through it and becomes soft when current is stopped?

Tags: current

Is there any material that can harden when electricity is passed through it and soften when current is stopped?

I basically want to use this material in a glove. The glove should get tough and difficult to bend when I pass electric or magnetic field through it. And once the field is removed, it should get back to how a normal glove works.

The best options to be used seem to be the Electrorheological or the Magnetorheological fluids but there seems to be a problem for both-
1) Which fluid can I use for Electrorheological application. Can it be made at home via some chemical or physical reaction?
2) If I use a mixture of Iron fillings and vegetable oil as a magnetorheological fluid, how do I create a magnetic field using arduino?

Comment: A pile of iron filings? Also see [smart fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_fluid)

Comment: A human body? (I kid, I kid...)

Comment: [Electrorheological fluid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrorheological_fluid)?

Comment: Historically, a frog's leg.

Comment: What is the application or is it ahem (blush) a medical problem you er.. um... have?

Comment: @Andyaka "for a friend".

Comment: @EugeneSh. how exactly can I use iron filling in this case? And which smart fluid can I use? Is there any smart fluid that I can buy in local stores?

Comment: @RogerRowland Which electrotheological fluid can I use?

Comment: @Andyaka not for medical problem :3

Comment: All these comments (except maybe the smart fluid one) are pretty much efforts as humor. I suspect that maybe there is no such thing as what you want. Maybe you could explain a little more about the application. Also, a precise definition of "tough" could help, if you are not at liberty to disclose the actual application.

Comment: There are attempts to make a clutch for automotive use with fluids that react to electric or magnetic fields - maybe search for papers.

Comment: added required information to the question

Comment: Bruce Wayne's got some that makes his cape work. Try emailing Morgan Freeman.

Comment: @ReshamPanth: Were you successful in making the fluid (silicone oil and corn starch) and using it as ElectroRheologicalFluid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got good news and bad news.

The good news is that I know that the exact material you are looking for exists. I happened to come across a TEDx talk on bionics where a mention and video of such a material that is flexible and compliant, and turns stiff and rigid when voltage is applied. The video can be seen here (The link starts at the part I mentioned): https://youtu.be/CDsNZJTWw0w?t=7m13s.

However, the bad news is there is no clear place I can find to get this peculiar material, all the presenter said was that it is developed by [SRI International](https://www.sri.com/).

Addressing your other question on how to make a magnetic field with an Arduino, that can be achieved with the help of some other components including a MOSFET and an inductor.

The inductor is basically a coil of wire, usually wrapped around a core, where upon the application of current passing through the coils, a magnetic field is created, which is used to store energy. This is precisely how an electromagnet works. Though the amount of current required to establish a strong magnetic field with an inductor exceeds the max value allowed for Arduino pins, the MOSFET is used to act as a switch controlled by signals from the Arduino.

Hope this helps, good luck finding out how to get the material, and be sure to tell me if you do!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That video contains exactly the stuff that I want. But as you mentioned, it seems difficult to get my hands on it. One option that I found on the web is corn starch + silicone oil. This guy says it works great- http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=246224.msg1824658#msg1824658

Comment: @ReshamPanth No worries. There you go, corn starch and silicone oil, never knew that worked. I'll have to try that out.